# Problems with excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I created a sheet with tables and I duplicated that sheet to create 3 more. Then I added formulas in tables in first sheet where I used table cells from other sheets. All formulas were structured references. My expectation was that if I add/remove any line above or below any tables, the formulas shall not be affected. But it seems that if I add/remove a line above or below the tables in other sheets, the formulas in tables in first sheet get messed up. Any suggestion how I can ensure that formulas will remain unaffected?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It appears when you copied the sheets it linked the tables. Was this your intent? What version of Excel are you using (assuming 2010 or later). What have you attempted to resolve this? Can you give us an example of your tables?

Comment: Hi, I didn't want to link the tables. How can I check and remove the links? When I was trying out different options, I faced the other problem where I was not able to get the structured references for some table cells etc.

Comment: I am not sure. I was unable to duplicate this problem with some tables I have in a workbook. How did you copy them? Did you copy the sheet or copy the tables to a blank sheet?

Comment: I just copied the sheet

Comment: Check the formulas. The structured references are probably still pointing to the table originally created [table_name].

Comment: All references are correct. It seems that structured references are anyway converted to absolute  cell ids when formulas are executed and that is causing the issue. One would expect that structured references would use start cell of a table as reference when calculating formulas.